# SBT publishing via SSH key auth not working

Tags: scala, maven, jvm, sbt, xsbt

My question is: Why can't I publish from SBT to my server via SSH?

### Context:

I am developing a scala library and I want to publish it to a remote repository with SBT v0.12.3 over SSH (using an SFTP resolver). The relevant portion of my project/Build.scala SBT settings file is configured as prescribed by https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Resolvers:

```
publishTo <<= version { v =>
    Some(Resolver.sftp(
        "My Repository",
        "example.com",
        "/var/www/public_html/repositories/" + (
            if (v.trim.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")) { "snapshots" } else { "releases" }
        )
    ))
},
resolvers ++= Seq(
    {
        import java.io.File
        val privateKeyFile: File = new File(sys.env("HOME") + "/.ssh/id_rsa")
        Resolver.ssh("scala-sh", "example.com") as("my-username", privateKeyFile) withPermissions("0644")
    },
    ...
),
```

When I run `sbt publish`, things go fine until the authorization, where it still attempts to prompt me for login/password.  When I run it locally, it brings up the username/password prompt, and when I try to publish remotely while SSH'd in to a machine it fails with a `java.awt.HeadlessException`.  The result appears to be that the desired private-key type of authentication is not being attempted.

Here is a log of the remote session publish attempt:

```
> sbt-version
[info] 0.12.3

> publish
[info] Packaging /home/me/my-lib/target/scala-2.10.1/my-lib_2.10.1-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Wrote /home/me/my-lib/target/scala-2.10.1/my-lib_2.10.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[info] :: delivering :: org.example#my-lib_2.10.1;SNAPSHOT :: SNAPSHOT :: release :: Sun Apr 21 12:48:59 PDT 2013
[info]  delivering ivy file to /home/me/my-lib/target/scala-2.10.1/ivy-SNAPSHOT.xml
[info] Generating API documentation for main sources...
model contains 75 documentable templates
[info] API documentation generation successful.
[info] Packaging /home/me/my-lib/target/scala-2.10.1/my-lib_2.10.1-SNAPSHOT-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Packaging my-lib-SNAPSHOT.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:publish for the full output.
[error] (*:publish) java.awt.HeadlessException:
[error] No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
[error] Total time: 35 s, completed Apr 21, 2013 12:49:33 PM
```

It fails because there is no X11 display.  This is unexpected behavior because the SBT project configuration is set to use private key authentication (see `resolvers` above).

So far I can think of 2 possible causes for the problem, detailed below.

### Possible cause #1: Misconfiguration of SBT

**Is there a problem in my configuration above?**

### Possible cause #2: Hitting an Ivy bug from an old version

At time of writing, I am using the latest SBT, 0.12.3. Maybe the version of Ivy being used by SBT is old. The more I think about it, the less likely this seems, but I haven't been able to rule it out yet.

**How can I find out what version of Ivy SBT is using?**

and then..

***IF* it is old, is there a way to get SBT to use a newer version of ivy?**

There is another relevant question, see [ivy ssh publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12486604/293064), which references[0] an [Old Ivy bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-783) which caused `java.awt.HeadlessExceptions`.

[0] [ivy ssh publisher](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12486604/293064)

- "Which version of Ivy are you using? There is a Jira Bug for Version 2.0 : [issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-783](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-783) which should be fixed now."
- "Seems like if I upgrade to ivy 2.3 rc-2. SSH publish works."

Comment: The full stack trace would probably help a lot to diagnose this. Can you grab it Does `Stack trace suppressed: run last *:publish for the full output` give you enough info to recover it?

Answer (score 1):

It may after all be an Ivy version related bug. I am using SBT 0.12.2, which AFAIK is using Ivy 2.0. I am looking at the Ivy cache, located in `~/.ivy2/cache/`, where Ivy creates a bunch of XML log files for the dependencies it has resolved, and I can see Ivy `module version 2.0` in every XML file generated.

I don't know of a way to update the Ivy version used by SBT, but judging by the default SBT documentation, a possible solution is to manually upgrade Ivy and make sure the default machine wide path points to the right Ivy version.

Then run `sbt clean` or `sbt update` to re-fetch dependencies and allow Ivy to regenerate XML config files, etc. for the new Ivy version. More on SBT dependency management [HERE](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki/Library-Management):

> Ivy Home Directory
>
> By default, sbt uses the standard Ivy home directory location
>   ${user.home}/.ivy2/. This can be configured machine-wide, for use by
>   both the sbt launcher and by projects, by setting the system property
>   sbt.ivy.home in the sbt startup script (described in Setup).
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> java -Dsbt.ivy.home=/tmp/.ivy2/ ...
> ```

**Update**

By checking the SBT Scala source code for the latest version, the version issue is confirmed again. Even SBT 0.13 appears to be using Ivy version 2.0.0, not 2.3. Have a look at the SBT source code, specifically the last few lines of [THIS](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Ivy.scala#L638) file.

Comment: I've reproduced you're observations by removing my ~/.ivy2 directory and running ``sbt clean``.  This displayed ``org.apache.ivy#ivy;2.2.0!ivy.jar (542ms)`` when it grabbed the ivy library.  At any rate, I'll file this as a bug with the SBT project.  Thank you for your help alex23.

Comment: I did the override like you said, and renamed all ivy-*2.3* to ivy-*2.2*, but I still saw ``delivering ivy file to /Users/me/my-lib/target/scala-2.10.1/ivy-2.1.22-SNAPSHOT.xml`` when I ran ``sbt  publish``, and it still prompted me for username/password.